Interpreting Row Equivalence in the Context of Maps
I have been exploring linear algebra for the last month and a half. My textbook, Linear Algebra by Jim Hefferon (2020), drives home the point that matrices are primarily a tool for representing maps. In this way, one can interpret any matrix in the context of maps, providing a greater understanding (and affording a higher-level way to approach proof and computation). Throughout the course, I have also learned three different relations between matrices; row-equivalence, matrix-equivalence, and similarity. Each of these definitions has a computational, matrix-oriented definition. For example, the matrix-oriented definition of matrix-equivalence is as follows:

Along with this matrix-oriented definition, both matrix-equivalence and similarity possess a map interpretation. For example, the map-oriented definition of matrix-equivalence is as follows:

While there is a matrix-oriented definition of row equivalence, my textbook does not outline a map-oriented definition. That is, what does it mean for two matrices to be row-equivalent in the context of maps? I have tried searching online, and I cannot seem to get a clear answer.

Row equivalence is a special case of matrix equivalence in which one of the bases can be chosen to be the standard basis. Matrix equivalence is a more general notion which allows for any choice of both bases.
The row-theoretic definition says that matrix $A$ is row equivalent to matrix $B$ if there is a series of row operations transforming $A$ into $B$. Because row operations are encoded by multiplication by elementary matrices, this means that $A$ is row equivalent to $B$ if there is a series of elementary (thus invertible) matrices $E_1$, $E_2$, ..., $E_n$ such that $B = E_nE_{n-1}\cdots E_2E_1A$. Hence, $A$ is row equivalent to $B$ if and only if there is an invertible matrix $E$ such that $B = EA$.
Here we see the connection to matrix equivalence; for $P$ we choose $E$, representing some nonstandard basis, and for $Q$ we choose $I$, representing the standard basis.

Thank you! After reading your response, though, I think we can generalize further. That is, if two matrices are row equivalent, then they represent the same map with respect to the same domain basis but a different codomain basis; this shared domain basis need not be the standard basis.
